# How to use Spring security with Primefaces

Tags: spring, primefaces, spring-security

I have found so many examples but the problem is all of them are using `JSP/JSF` as view. The problem is they always use `j_username` as username input id and `j_password` as password id. What I found is these names are standard names. Primefaces doesn't allow me to give name to `p:inputtext` component. Do you have any solution?

Here is an example : http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_13.html

Comment: when your form is generated, what are names of username field and password field?

Comment: which version of Spring Security are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j_username` and `j_password` are only default values in Spring Security. You can customize these names as you expected. To do this, you set values for `password-parameter` and `username-parameter` as below:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.html" 
    default-target-url="/welcome.html"
    always-use-default-target="true" 
    authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error" 
    password-parameter="your_value" 
    username-parameter="your_value"/>
```

I'm using Spring Security 3.1. With another version, the configuration is possibly something like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a normal HTML form pointing to the URL of login controller instead of a Primefaces tags:

```
<form name='f' action="/j_spring_security_check" method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
    <input type='password' name='j_password' />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post directly to `j_spring_security_check`, but sometimes it might come handy to do it programmatically to combine both worlds.

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.login}" ajax="false">
<h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" />
<h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" />
```

with h `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"`

in your loginController:

```
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getExternalContext();

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
```

Comment: Small side note: Depending if you use spring authentication handlers or not, you might want to add `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();`